# On $\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{c-i\infty}^{c+i\infty}\eta'(s)\frac{x^s}{s\zeta(s)}ds$, for $c>1$, where $\eta(s)$ is the Dirichlet Eta function

Tags: analytic-number-theory, contour-integration, dirichlet-series, mobius-function, mellin-transform

When I was combining the identities from this article from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mertens_function) for the Mertens function, I've asked my an open question, if you can solve it from a standard viewpoint it is appreciated, and should be a nice exercise to learn basics about these functions and methods in analytic number theory.

> **Question.** Are there some *substancials differences* between the second Chebyshev function $\psi(x)=\sum_{n\leq x}\Lambda(n)$ (where thus $\Lambda(n)$ is the von Mangoldt function) and this different function $$\phi(x):=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{c-i\infty}^{c+i\infty}\eta'(s)\frac{x^s}{s\zeta(s)}ds,\tag{1}$$ for $c>1$ where we are denoting with $\eta(s)$ the alternating zeta function ([see in this Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_eta_function))?
>
> Note the similarity of my definition because I wrote the factor $\eta'(s)$ instead of the derivative of the Riemann's Zeta function. With the words *substancials differences* I am asking if you can tell us how trackle and write (if it is feasible) the corresponding definition of $\phi(x)$ as a step  function. That is, can you provide me a discussion about similarities and differences of the new and old step functions? I say the more important facts, see also below if you want to expand the answer. **Thanks in advance.**

Comment: (1) seems like the inverse Mellin transform which can be computed by contour integration.

Comment: @ZaidAlyafeai Not really, with the residue theorem you'll get the [Riemann explicit formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Explicit_formulae_(L-function)#Riemann.27s_explicit_formula)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\eta(s) = (1-2^{1-s})\zeta(s), \qquad \eta'(s) = (1-2^{1-s}) \zeta'(s)+ \ln 2 \ 2^{1-s} \zeta(s)$$ For $ Re(s) > 1$ :  $$\frac{\eta'(s)}{\zeta(s)} =  s\int_1^\infty  (\psi(x)-2\psi(x/2)+ 2\ln 2 \ 1_{x > 2} )x^{-s-1}dx$$
By inverse Mellin/Laplace/Fourier transform, for $c > 1$ and $x > 0$ :
$$\psi(x)-2\psi(x/2)+ 2\ln 2 \ 1_{x > 2}=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{c-i\infty}^{c+i\infty}\frac{\eta'(s)}{\zeta(s)}\frac{x^s}{s}ds$$
$\scriptstyle\text{as usual with Fourier transforms, at the discontinuities } (x \in \mathbb{N}) \text{ we define } \psi(x) \text{ to be the mean value of its left and right limits}$

Comment: Thanks! Then $\phi(x)=\psi(x)-2\psi(x/2)+ 2\ln 2 \ 1_{x > 2}.$ Was an elegant answer for the main Question. congratullations. I hope that some user try to find a $\tilde{M}(x)$ and its Mellin transform, if it has mathematical meaning, I believe that yes.

Comment: I am agree with your words, many thanks.

Comment: @user243301 What you say doesn't mean anything. What do you want more than what I wrote ?

Comment: I accept it, in fact I've deleted the additional attached to the main question, thus no problem.

Comment: @user243301 Tu réalises pourquoi il faut lire un cours sur la transformée de Fourier/Laplace ? et pourquoi tu ne supprimes pas tes commentaires pourris dans un anglais plus qu'approximatif qui donnent envie au lecteur de partir ?

Comment: Yes, of course I know that is a tool to analyze and synthesize functions. It is very very important. You are right with this advice 1000%. And  I know that my english is very bad, I will never learn english.

Comment: Are you here? I hope that you are no angry.

Comment: @user243301 Tu sais démontrer ce que j'ai écrit ?

Comment: I believe that if my calulations are rights I can get, but not obviously with your knowledges, I say that I understand it simbolically: the first identity is derivation using the product rule and that $(2^x)'=2^x\log 2$; for $\Re s>1$ we divide by $\zeta(s)$ to get $\frac{\eta'(s)}{\zeta(s)}=\frac{\zeta'(s)}{\zeta(s)}-2^{1-s}\frac{\zeta'(s)}{\zeta(s)}+2^{1-s}\log 2$, we combine with $\frac{\zeta'(s)}{\zeta(s)}=-s\int_1^\infty \psi(x)x^{s-1}dx $, the change of variable $-2\cdot2^{-s}\frac{\zeta'(s)}{\zeta(s)}=2s\int_1^\infty \psi(\frac{u}{2})u^{-s}\frac{du}{u}$

Comment: and $\int_2^\infty x^{-s-1}dx=\frac{2^{-s}}{s}$ for $\Re s>0$, thus $\Re s>1$. Finally you combine with the theorem of inversion. Many thanks, as you see I try follow your great answer to try learn. I am interested in learn modern mathematics but it is difficult to encourage myself to study more in a right way.

Comment: @user243301  C'est bien. Donc tu dois démontrer le [théorème d'inversion de Fourier/Laplace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_inversion_theorem), en commençant par un cours sur les séries de Fourier

Comment: No I don't know how prove neither the theorem of Fourier-Laplace nor the inverse theorem. In the past I've studied such issues in a course from my university. I am going to read the Wikipedia's article, good nights.